# Could not share printer driver

Tags: windows-7, printer, hp-laserjet

I have a PC connect to a HP LaserJet Professional P1606dn Printer. I want to share to another PC in LAN but the driver is not automatically installed when double click on shared Printer icon. Please help me!

[image]

Comment: Which PC is running Windows 7? Both? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to **add drivers** to the `printer sharing PC` (the PC which shares the printer) so that other PCs can install the printer driver suitable for their OS (32bit, 64bit, etc.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]